# MySQL now() change timezone

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I'm using the following INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO messages SET `to` = '".$to."', `from` = '".$this->userid."', `title` = '".$title."', `message` = '".$message."', `created` = NOW()
```

However, it uses my server time (America/Montreal). I want time zone of Asia (Asia/Calcutta)

Is this possible with the same query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would want to go ahead and use the `CONVERT_TZ()` function in MySQL.  It's based off the [Olson database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANA_time_zone_database) which your operating system uses.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) is the documentation.

Comment: HI THX BUT NOT WORKING "INSERT INTO messages SET `to` = '".$to."', `from` = '".$this->userid."', `title` = '".$title."', `message` = '".$message."', `created` = CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'America/Phoenix', 'Asia/Calcutta)"

Comment: Do a subselect on the created, SELECT CONVERT_TZ(now(),'US/Eastern','US/Central');

Comment: Rather, you might need to populate the timezone tables, ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523286/mysql-convert-tz

mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql

Answer (score 15):

Better use the SQL format directly in your query:

```
..`created` = CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'SYSTEM','Asia/Calcutta')..
```

Comment: thanks for using SYSTEM instead of the other hacky solutions

Comment: thanks. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808160/mysql-time-zones for more details on timezone

Answer (score 8):

After you open the connection to MySQL, run the following as a query:

```
SET time_zone = timezone;
```

Then all functions you do will run for that timezone for that connection (i.e. until you close the "link" to the database".

If you have the appropriate permissions you can lock it "permanently" / globaly. Tiemzone strings are standard strings as you have in your question.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$myDateTime = new DateTime('2012-05-23 17:01', new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
$myDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
echo $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

After modification to above code, such as desired format; you could use `$myDateTime` variable to insert into database.

Answer (score 0):

Small change from @Vlado 's answer

```
..`created` = CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@time_zone,'Asia/Calcutta')..
```

Cus now() method will use timezone variable even when global timezone changed or session timezone changed

Answer (score 0):

1. To set a Session Timezone (GMT +5.30)

```
SET time_zone = "+05:30";
```

2. Query (considering "processedAt" as datetime)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE processedAt < NOW() AND processedAt IS NOT NULL;
```

3. Check the Global and Current Session timezone

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;
```

Or if you are using PHP, set this at the top of your script

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
```

and use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` instead of Mysql `NOW()`