# How to get total row counted in different timezone in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

This is my sql query. It return total rows in UTC timezone. I want to count completed_date field in different timezone. like America/Los_Angeles timezone format. I heard that i need to use something GROUP or DATE function but i don't get any idea.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM `team_users` 
 WHERE (`completed_date` BETWEEN  '2016-04-27 00:00:00' AND  '2016-04-27 23:59:59')
```

Comment: Do you have a column called `timezone`?

Comment: Convert the dates from from the local timezone to UTC before you put them in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work to convert `completed_date` so that you can compare your dates with it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM `team_users` 
  WHERE (CONVERT_TZ(`completed_date`, '+00:00', '-08:00')
  BETWEEN  '2016-04-27 00:00:00' AND  '2016-04-27 23:59:59')
```

Using the timezone offsets is problematic as America/Los_Angeles is `-07:00` to day because of Daylight saving time, but otherwise `-08:00`.

You can use `UTC` and then `PST` for Pacific Standard Time or `America/Los_Angeles` if your system has been configured to use named timezones: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: Does `PST` work without loading the timezone data in MySQL?

Comment: @Mike: Probably not: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: If you have to load the timezone data in MySQL anyway presumably `America/Los_Angeles` should always work as well, wouldn't it?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to think about how you would go from `America/Los_Angeles` to `PST` or `-08:00` programatically.

Comment: Mike! i used -07:00 and it worked but it doesn't work with UTC PST.... I should set timezone?

Comment: Well, it works with -7 now because of daylight savings time. Normally -8.

Comment: I would use named timezones *always*. Don't try to convert to an offset or you're into a world of hurt. If timezones aren't loaded in MySQL and you can't load them, you can do the conversion in PHP instead. As far as I know they are always available in PHP (even if they may be outdated and need to be updated manually). See http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php.

Comment: Also for loading timezones into MySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15419843/811240